Issue with Internal Links in Wagtail RichTextEditor
I'm using the Wagtail RichTextEditor, which has an option to add links. Using this link option, I can upload both internal and external links. When I add an external link, it works fine. However, when I try to add an internal link and publish the page, the link appears with a broken link symbol. Additionally, in the API, the href attribute is showing as None.
Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I resolve it?
My code is like this:
class CustomizeRichTextBlock(RichTextBlock):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(features=[
            'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'bold', 'italic', 'ol', 'ul', 'hr', 
            'link', 'image', 'blockquote', 'mark', 'embed', 'code', 'superscript', 
            'subscript', 'strikethrough','text-alignment','underline'
        ], **kwargs)

    def add_link_style(self, html_content):
        # Add the `style` attribute to all <a> tags
        styled_content = re.sub(r'<a ', r'<a style="color: #2FC1D4;" ', html_content)
        return styled_content    
        

    def get_api_representation(self, value, context=None) -> str:
        # Generate the initial HTML content from rich text
        html_content = expand_db_html(value.source)
        
        # Add custom link styling
        styled_content = self.add_link_style(html_content)

         # Replace empty paragraphs with a unique placeholder for line breaks
        styled_content = re.sub(r'<p[^>]*>\s*</p>',r'<p><br /></p>', styled_content)

        # Return the final content
        return styled_content
     


This would happen if you have no site records set up under Settings -> Sites, or the page you're linking to exists somewhere in the page tree that isn't covered by any site records.
If you have a site structure like
Home
|
|- Blog
|  |- First blog post
|  |- Second blog post
|
|- People
   |- Alice
   |- Bob

then there needs to be a site record with a root page of 'Home'. This serves two purposes:

When a request comes in for a URL like /people/alice/, it provides the starting point for locating that page - look for a child named 'people', then 'alice'
When outputting the URL of a given page, the path is computed relative to that root page - so it's /people/alice/ rather than /alice/ or /home/people/alice/

Since you're working with get_api_representation, you're probably building a 'headless' site where Wagtail isn't responsible for serving the pages, so point 1 doesn't apply - but you're still relying on Wagtail to return the URLs to linked pages, so you still need the site record for point 2.

I've checked that the Site record is correctly set up in Wagtail with the root page and the site URL is configured. The URL paths for pages are being generated correctly.
Could there be something else in the Wagtail configuration that might be causing this issue?
